# How to disable battery-indicator on Ubuntu 17.10? (GNOME's alternative of 'indicator-power')

Tags: unity, gnome, indicator, battery, 17.10

I want to disable the battery-indicator alerts on Ubuntu 17.10. On earlier (Unity) distros that'd be done by running `sudo apt-get remove indicator-power`
What indicator does GNOME use?

(My battery stopped recharging, so it works only with the power cord connected. But every so often, the "Critically Low" battery indicator starts flashing  followed by the 'device disconnected' alert sound. 
(I think the issue is the battery draws power, just enough for the board to recognize it, then dies immediately OR maybe the exact opposite, the power flow weakens for a second, going from powered to battery for a second then back back to power)

Answer (score 0):

Open "dconf Editor", go to `org` folder and search for "recall", you'll found these:

`notify-perhaps-recall`

`percentage-action`

`percentage-critical`

`percentage-low`

[image: View options screenshot]

Set "`notify-perhaps-recall`" to *OFF*

and set `percentage-action`, `percentage-critical` & `percentage-low` to "`0`".

Comment: HI! It didn't solve the problem. Did you check it?